# Qt app crashes when trying to connect two widgets

Tags: qt, plugins, qt4

I'm trying to connect a label created by a plugin with a action created by another plugin in my app. So after i app finds and loads both plugins , i try to connect them , and here app crashes.

```
connect(myAction->getAction(), SIGNAL(triggered()),myLabel, SLOT(setLabelText()));
```

myAction->getAction() - this method returns a pointer of created action

setLabelText()   - must change label text

If i remove that line , my app works fine , action is added to menu , and label is on window.

Methods from plugin which returns an action

```
QAction* ActionPlugin::newAction() {

    myAction = new QAction("Show text",this);

    return myAction;
}

QAction* ActionPlugin::getAction() {

 return myAction;

}
```

Methods of plugin which return a label

```
QLabel* LabelPlugin::newLabel() {

    label = new QLabel("This plugin works");

    return label;
}

void LabelPlugin::setTextforLabel() {

    label->setText("This plugin works fine");

}
```

Each time app find and loads plugins , it increments a variable named verify (an integer) , if it's value is 2 , then i can connect those two widgets

```
if (verify == 2)
               connect(myAction->getAction(), SIGNAL(triggered()),myLabel, SLOT(setLabelText()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is crashing *when it hits that line*, I'd guess that either the pointer being returned from `getAction` or `myLabel` is uninitialized or else has been left pointing into never-never land. Could you post the code for `getAction()`? Are you initializing `myLabel` before this statement is reached?

Comment: Sorry, I still can't tell what's going on, but I will say there are some odd ownership decisions in that code. The QAction will be owned by the ActionPlugin, but the QLabel must be owned by the caller of newLabel(). Is the ActionPlugin instance perhaps going out of scope before your connect statement, and thus deleting the QAction it owns? Also, is `myAction` both the name of a private QAction instance within ActionPlugin *and* an instance of ActionPlugin?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that "newAction" method is ever called?

add qDebug`("created action");` before `return myAction;` line in newAction method

// EDIT:

[QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493506/qobjectconnect-cannot-connect-null)

Show us your loader code, because I can clearly see that your current problem is strictly related to problem that you "resolved" in earlier question.