# QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)

Tags: qt, plugins, qt4, widget

I try to load to plugins.  If they are loaded with success , then i must connect returned widgets.

With one plugin i create an action and add it to a menu , with another plugin i create a label and add it to window. Even if i get this error during runtime (when app loads plugins) , these two widgets are created and are visible.  But there is no connection between them.

This is how i try to connect widgets

```
QObject *plugin = pluginLoader.instance();
if (plugin) {
    myAction = qobject_cast<ActionInterface *>(plugin);

    if (myAction) {
        pluginMenu->addAction(myAction->newAction());
        verify ++;
    }

    myLabel = qobject_cast<LabelInterface *>(plugin);

    if (myLabel) {            
        layout->addWidget(myLabel->newLabel());
        verify++;
    }

    if (verify == 2)
        connect(myAction, SIGNAL(pushMyAction()),
            myLabel, SLOT(setTextforLabel()));
    }

    ...
}
```

Error message is :

> QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::pushMyAction() to LabelPlugin::setTextforLabel()

Comment: We don't see here where you set verify to 0.  So perhaps you are carrying over a value of 1 from a previous verify...it is incremented by one because myLabel is not null, and then you have it at 2 even though myAction is null.  Otherwise, if verify is 2 and myAction is null...something else is wrong here...

Comment: @HostileFork  I set it in class constructor MainWindow::MainWindow() { verify = 0;  ... }

Comment: Well isn't the point of this code here that you are using the verify count to confirm that both `myAction` and `myLabel` are not null?  If you don't reset it each time this code is run, then it doesn't provide that guarantee.  And you can't connect a null object pointer.

Comment: but why it's  null ? myAction was used to add an action to menu , and did not trigger any error, but in connect method is shown as null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QObject *plugin = pluginLoader.instance();
if (plugin) {

    if (plugin->inherits("ActionInterface")) {
        myAction = qobject_cast<ActionInterface *>(plugin);
        pluginMenu->addAction(myAction->newAction());
    }

    if (plugin->inherits("LabelInterface")) {            
        myLabel = qobject_cast<LabelInterface *>(plugin);
        layout->addWidget(myLabel->newLabel());
    }

    if (myLabel && myAction)
        connect(myAction, SIGNAL(pushMyAction()),
            myLabel, SLOT(setTextforLabel()));
    }

    ...
}
```

Remove this "ugly" verify counter. Remember to initialize myLabel and myAction with NULL

Answer (score 3):

You have two different plugins.  Apparently one can be cast to an `ActionInterface` but not a `LabelInterface`, and the other can be cast to a `LabelInterface` but not an `ActionInterface`.

Your idea here seems to be that once you have both plugins loaded (and a verify count of 2) then it's safe to make a connect call between these plugins.  However you appear to be trying to cast the second loaded plugin to serve as *both* the signal and the slot.  This is because each time you run the code you overwrite both `myAction` and `myLabel`.  So at minimum:

```
QObject* plugin = pluginLoader.instance();
if (plugin) {
    ActionInterface* myActionTemp = qobject_cast<ActionInterface*>(plugin);

    if (myActionTemp) {
        myAction = myActionTemp;
        pluginMenu->addAction(myAction->newAction());
        verify++;
    }

    LabelInterface* myLabelTemp = qobject_cast<LabelInterface*>(plugin);

    if (myLabelTemp) {
        myLabel = myLabelTemp;            
        layout->addWidget(myLabel->newLabel());
        verify++;
    }

    /* if (myAction and myLabel) would be less convoluted... */
    if (verify == 2) { 
        connect(myAction, SIGNAL(pushMyAction()),
            myLabel, SLOT(setTextforLabel()));
    }

    ...
}
```

Still, this looks like a fairly brittle design that could use some rethinking...!

Comment: To be honest I understood what question author wanted to achieve after your answer. +1 for udnerstanding that reaaaly flawed design.